# select option mouseenter issue in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an issue where I need to find out the hovered option of select/dropdown, I have found it on chrome but not able to find it internet explorer.

I have tried below code but didn't work.

```js
$('select').on('mouseenter', 'option', function(e) {
  debugger;
  console.log('option found');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="optionList" id="optionList" onclick="rankFeatures(false)" size="5">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The `mouseenter` method cannot be reliably used cross-browser on `option` elements. If you need this behaviour you would need to use a library which converts a `select` in to a group of HTML elements which can be manipulated in this way

Comment: or hover event if possible?

Comment: No, same issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please suggest any free library for this ?

Comment: [`Select2`](https://select2.org/)

Comment: but its converting it in ul and li..

Comment: That's correct. It's the only way to do what you need cross-browser.